# How do I use a Django view to remove logic from templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have read that don't use logic in your Django templates. Use a view. Yes, I can figure out why that is. But I don't really know how to implement it to change for example with this:

```
{% if '/admin/' in request.path or '/users/' in request.path %}
<div class="col-md-full">
{% else %}
<div class="col-md-8">
{% endif %}
```

How would a view do the above?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing why it uses different grid sizes for the admin/users, the logic you're showing is for modifying the ui anyway so its not too bad having it in the template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its bad to include *business logic* in your templates, that is to say logic that involves how your models work or behave and any other logic that affects the purpose of the web site/app.

The logic you've shown is to differentiate ui elements, also known as *presentation logic*, and that is ok because it directly modifies what should be shown to the user and has no effect whatsoever on the backend.